# How to read Mutual Funds's Exp ratio and its Yrs Average Annual Returns

Tags: investing, mutual-funds

I have read the following comments on this forum:

> Over long horizons, you absolutely want to minimise the expense ratio
> – a seemingly puny 2% fee p.a. can cost you a third of your savings
> over 35 years.

I am confused about this. If a mutual fund says its 15 Yrs Average Annual Return is 10%, is this 10% the number that took out the 2% Exp Ratio cost already?

If the 10% does not take out the 2% Exp Ratio cost, do we still have an 8% (10% - 2%) return? Can I think those numbers like this?